# Which JS event triggers when app moves to foreground from background

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, dojo, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a hybrid mobile app using Dojo. On sign in page when I entered id and password and moved the app to background, I have to clear the id and password fields when app comes to the foreground again.

Which JS event can help me ?

Comment: A schema could help

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the resume event from cordova.

```
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
function onResume() {
    setTimeout(function() {
            // TODO: do your thing!
        }, 0);
}
```

This is from the [cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#resume)

Comment: I tried but probably trying at a wrong place. Could you please provide me some more details.  Do I also need to import Cordova reference  in my JS file ?

Comment: To use cordova you should follow the steps in the [guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html#create-the-app)

Comment: I am already using Cordova, but when I am trying to register a listener for resume event, it's not getting fired. below is teh code .   document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false),
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false),